# Why is this not a matroid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, matroids

If I recall correctly both of these definitions are equivalent:

1. $(E,I)$ is an independence system and satisfies the augmentation property.
2. $(E,I)$ is an independence system and all maximal independent sets in I have the same size.

However I would say that the following system satisfies the second definition but not the first:

$(\{1,2,3,4\},\{A|$ all numbers in A have equal parity$\})$

The maximal independent sets are $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$, but at the same time if we take $A_1=\{1\}$ and $A_2=\{2,4\}$ we can't find any $a \in \{2,4\} \setminus \{1\}$ so that $(\{1\} \cup a) \in I$.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Note: The term "[(abstract) simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex)" is a common synonym for "[independence system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_system)", and I'll use the former term here.

Your first definition is one way to define a matroid. Your second definition defines a class of objects called *pure simplicial complexes*. As you point out in your question, there are pure simplicial complexes that are not matroids.

But what about the converse?

The fact that every basis of a matroid has the same size (equal to the rank of the matroid) follows directly from the augmentation property. It follows that the independent sets of any matroid form a pure simplicial complex. So we have the following chain of strict inclusions:

$$ \mathrm{Matroids} \subsetneq \mathrm{Pure~Simplicial~Complexes} \subsetneq \mathrm{Simplicial~Complexes}$$